# Alternative to "Brown-Nosing"

Tags: word-choice

I'm looking for a G-rated word that will serve as an alternative to "Brown-Nosing."  I'm thinking that there is a word on par with "flattering" (but with a closer definition) and "buttering up" (though less tacky).

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers. Requests for single-word or phrase definitions are off-topic for us but acceptable on English if properly phrased. I'll ask the mods to migrate.

Comment: Lauren's correct, however if you expand the question to include how to write such characters, it could be useful for others...

Comment: I'm sorry to say this would probably be closed on English if it were sent there in its current form.

Comment: However, they do accept word-request questions, with some guidelines: http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info If you're willing to edit this to fit, I'll send it over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People who are "brown-nosers" are sycophants. The definition of 'brown nose' is to curry favour with someone, usually by acting very obsequiously.

Now, depending on your audience, this could better be described as:

- sycophantic
- fawning
- ingratiating
- toadying
- groveling
- crawling
- bootlicking

And so on.

The first literary example that springs to mind is Grima Wormtongue from Lord of the Rings, have a look at how Tolkien models his behaviour and speech patterns, and how he describes him.